# Logstash and grok : Variables name determined from input

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, logstash-grok

I want to send multiple different syslog from my F5 LTM but I would to be able to send any kind of information without changing my Logstash configuration all the time.
For example today I have two iRules which can send two types of logs:

```
<134>Dec 16 11:55:01 XX-BIGIP02 tmm1[9224]: Rule /Common/Layer4_Logger <CLIENT_CLOSED>: Layer4 SFTP --Client 136.2.0.000:28075 --Vip 10.12.0.00:22 --Node 10.12.0.00:22 --ConnectedIn 106 --ClosedAfter 824
<132>Dec 16 12:02:03 XX-BIGIP02 tmm[9224]: Rule /Common/SSLv3_Logger <HTTP_REQUEST>: SSLv3 connexion detected from 202.00.000.254:64541 to 10.12.0.00:443 --URL as1.***.com/ed**s/ED**S.dll?ClientType=Es***036.39983&ClientInfoC=XaV%2FWcV***&Handler=Default2 --SSL SSLv3:RC4-SHA:128 --UserAgent "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; MS Web Services Client Protocol 2.0.50727.1891)"
```

Regarding the second line, this is what I was doing:

```
grok {
        match => { "message" => "%{SYSLOGTIMESTAMP:syslog_timestamp} %{SYSLOGHOST:syslog_hostname} %{DATA:syslog_program}(?:\[%{POSINT:syslog_pid}\])?: %{GREEDYDATA:syslog_message}" }
        add_field => [ "received_at", "%{@timestamp}" ]
    }
    grok {
        match => {"syslog_message" => "Rule %{DATA:F5_iRuleName} <%{DATA:F5_onEvent}>:.*?from %{IPORHOST:src_ip}(?:[: ]%{INT:src_port})? to (?:/Common/%{DATA:F5_Pool} )?%{IPORHOST:dest_ip}(?:[: ]%{INT:dest_port})?"}
    }
```

What I would like to do is catch in my syslog_message every

```
--VariableName Value
```

And have the variableName and value indexed in my Elasticsearch. Is this possible?

A simple regex to catch my stuff would be something like : (Just an example)

```
(--[A-Za-z0-9_]+)\s ([^\s]+?)
```

but I didn't find how I could say to grok that my first group catched should be a field in ES.

Thanks for your help,

Comment: This might be possible with the kv{} filter (key/value).

Comment: This will do the job indeed : thanks

Answer (score 0):

kv{} filter (key/value) does the work (instead of grok) : https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-kv.html